# How to test Azure slots when deploying bots

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-web-app-service

I use the Azure slots feature for deploying my bot:

1. Deploy to 'staging' slot
2. Azure start this instance
3. When up, I swap 'production' and 'staging' slots

I would like to test the staging instance before doing a slot, ideally using the Webchat test tool in Azure portal. However, I couldn't see a way to specify which slot instance this webchat tool points at.

Is there a way to test a bot running in a specific slot?

Comment: Did you end up with any satisfactory solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to test the staging instance before doing a slot, ideally using the Webchat test tool in Azure portal.

On [**Settings** blade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-settings), you can modify the **Messaging endpoint** to point to your bot application that is deployed on staging slot, then test it via WebChat.

*Change Messaging endpoint:*

[image]

*Test in WebChat:*

[image]

***Note***: I clone configuration from original app when I add staging slot.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that the bot in **production** will also refer the messaging endpoint which means that prod users will also end up referring the staging slot's bot even before the swap is made.

Comment: I don't *think* so, the staging slot has a different end point because it is on a different URL. The prod keys point to the endpoint which uses prod URL. I stand to be corrected though!

Comment: Ok, never got this to work and after raising an MS ticket, they said it wasn’t supported in the integrated web chat in the portal.